# appxupload package not being generated. Only test package is being generated

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, appx, appxmanifest

I am developing a universal windows app. When I try to create package using Store->Create App packages, it is creating only test packages. In AppPackages directory, I can find only one folder with _test.

How do I ensure that .appxupload package gets created that can be uploaded to windows store.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `Projekt.csproj.user` file if `AppxPackageIsForStore` is set to true.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ShowAllFiles</ProjectView>
    <AppxPackageIsForStore>True</AppxPackageIsForStore>
    <AppxShowAllApps>True</AppxShowAllApps>
    <AppxBuildConfigurationSelection>x86|x64|arm</AppxBuildConfigurationSelection>
  </PropertyGroup>
```